# onMouseMove doesnot work outside of element react

Tags: reactjs, svg, ecmascript-6

I have an svg element on which I am doing onMouseDown, OnMouseMove and onMouseUp. My problem is that as soon as the user leaves the element while still holding their mouse button down, it does not register the mousemove.
I want to keep the onMouseMove event on even after user leaves the element.

Here is my code:

```
Class School extents React.Component {
  onDragStartCircle = (e) {
    //taking the initial state
  }
  onDragCircle = () {
   // draging the element
  }
  onDragEndCircle = () {
    // saving data to the database
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <svg>
          <circle
            cx={50}
            cy={50}
            r={10} 
            fill="red"
            onMouseDown={this.onDragStartCircle}
            onMouseMove={this.onDragCircle}
            onMouseUp={this.onDragEndCircle}
           />
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have also tried onDragStart, onDrag these are not working. I am using es6.

Comment: `onMouseMove` will only be triggered on mouse moves over that specific element, that you bind that event to, I guess. So maybe you should consider binding these events to a container element or similar. The same holds true for that `mouseUp` event.

Comment: How will I bind the event with parent in react. Parent also have the onMouseMove, onMouseDown and onMouseUp events. @Hinrich

Comment: You can bind these events to basically every element in react.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of your code, whichs shows how to use a container to register events outside of that circle.

You should consider subscribing to the move event on drag start, and unsubscribing again on drag end, to prevent to much events firing. But this should get you started.

```js
class School extends React.Component {
  onDragStartCircle = (e) => {
    console.log('drag start')
  }
  onDragCircle = () => {
   console.log('move')
  }
  onDragEndCircle = () => {
    console.log('drag end')
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="container" 
        onMouseMove={this.onDragCircle}
        onMouseUp={this.onDragEndCircle}>
        <svg>
          <circle
            cx={50}
            cy={50}
            r={10} 
            fill="red"
            onMouseDown={this.onDragStartCircle}
            
           />
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <School />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the above solution can't solve my problem because my parent elements also have have onMouseMove, onMouseUp, onMouseDown events. @Hinrich

Comment: Then please povide a more complete example.